# Mocking boto3 calls actual boto3

Tags: python, boto3, moto

I'm writing some test for `boto3` functions and using the `moto` library to mock `boto3`.

The example they provide is as such:

```
import boto3
from moto import mock_ec2

def add_servers(ami_id, count):
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-1')
    client.run_instances(ImageId=ami_id, MinCount=count, MaxCount=count)

@mock_ec2
def test_add_servers():
    add_servers('ami-1234abcd', 2)

    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-1')
    instances = client.describe_instances()['Reservations'][0]['Instances']
    assert len(instances) == 2
    instance1 = instances[0]
    assert instance1['ImageId'] == 'ami-1234abcd'
```

However when I try something similar, using a trivial example here, by doing this:

```
def start_instance(instance_id):
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id])

@mock_ec2
def test_start_instance():
    start_instance('abc123')
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    instances = client.describe_instances()
    print instances

test_start_instance()

ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidInstanceID.NotFound) when calling the StartInstances operation: The instance ID '[u'abc123']' does not exist
```

Why is it actually making request to AWS when I clearly have the function wrapped in the mocker?

Comment: Also look into stuff like FakeS3 , if you need a real mock S3 services that let you store file temporarily to test apps functionality to S3.

Comment: I'm doing more EC2 work than anything but I will keep it in mind. Another cool library I saw was `placebo` which records your actual calls to AWS and stores the results in a directory which you can then call on to use for testing.

Comment: I usually test deployment script to deploy stuff on t2.nano/micro instance. Ijust swap out the t2 instance with actual instance for production

Comment: People who come here might be affected by [spulec/moto/issues/1793](https://github.com/spulec/moto/issues/1793)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the README.md of [moto for boto/boto3](https://github.com/spulec/moto),  I notice 
on the S3 connection code, there is a remarks

> # We need to create the bucket since this is all in Moto's 'virtual'
>   AWS account

If I am correct, the error shown is not AWS error, but Moto error.  You need to initialise all the mock resources you want to mock to the Moto virtual space. This mean, you need to use another script to use moto to mock "create_instance" before you can start the instance.

Comment: this is exactly it, I have posted my comment below as well. I will go ahead and accept as this is the same exact answer to my solution.

Answer (score 0):

So after reaching out to some of the contributors I was told that:

`Moto isn't like a MagicMock--it's an actual in-memory representation of the AWS resources. So you can't start an instance you haven't created, you can't create an instance in a vpc you haven't previously defined in Moto, etc.`

In order to use services that require a certain resource, you first have to create that mock service. For my function to work I went ahead and mocked a call to `create_instance` which I can then use to test further. Hope this helps those who stumble on this at some point in the future.